# How to prevent direct URL with Login Page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

So I have a login page and when an authenticated user logs in, the program redirects the user to

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx", false);
```

But my question is how to prevent the user from simply accessing the login protected webpage by inputting the direct URL.

Comment: are you using MVC? or asp.net?

Comment: I am using asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your web.config accordingly. if you already have system.web in your web.config. make sure you copy what inside only. because you cannot have multiple system.web in your web config. if you want to allow user to access another page without login. you can add another location path as  Login.aspx as many as you like.

```
<configuration>
    <location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is the "standard" way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a function in the WebForm1.aspx page to check to make sure the user is authenticated. For example, in pseudocode --

```
def WebForm1(request):

    if not user_is_authenticate():
        Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx", false);

    # Display Homepage here
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually handled with sessions which contain data, in this case about the validation state of the user.

```
if(/*user isn't validated*/)//HttpContext.Session[Userisvalidated]==false
Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx", false);
```

The code is untested and you can find more information about asp.net sseesion here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx or here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have copied this from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240#bookmark-7) if you want to read more. You should

> Generate the authentication ticket, encrypt it, create a cookie, add it to the response, and redirect the user [after logging in successfully]. This gives you more control in how you create the cookie. You can also include custom data along with the FormsAuthenticationTicket in this case.

Here is some code:

```
if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )
   {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
      string cookiestr;
      HttpCookie ck;
      tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
      cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
      ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
      if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
      ck.Expires=tkt.Expiration;    
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
      Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

      string strRedirect;
      strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
      if (strRedirect==null)
            strRedirect = "default.aspx";
         Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
   }
   else
      Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);
```

Here is another way to check if user is authenticated:

```
bool isAuthenticated = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```